# .Net MVC ActionLink inside a Button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button, actionlink

I have an action link inside a button that doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:60px;">
    <button class="btn-top btn-vitae shadow-bottom">
        <a href="/Help" target="_blank">Help</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

The link is supposed to go to ActionResult `Index` in the `HelpController`:

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Help/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What doesn't work? You cannot click on it or you get 404?

Comment: Why are you nesting an A tag inside a Button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if memory serves you need to swap them

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Help")"><input type="button" class="btn-top btn-vitae shadow-bottom" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `href="/Help"` with `@(Url.Action("Index", "Help"))`

Using Url.Action you will be sure that the correct url is generated no matter what routing you're using.

Answer (score 1):

your action link should include the controller name and action name like this

```
<a href="/Help/Index" target="_blank">Help</a>
```

or server side as suggested by @ssimeonov

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use Html.ActionLink (Instead of Anchor Tag) -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Index", "Home", null, new { target = "_blank" })
```